# Is there a way to query members collection in wix and get data from any member?

Tags: javascript, velo

I tried to query the `"Members/PrivateMembersData"` collection to get 3 members data (I'm the owner of the project), when I execute it from my account it's working fine but when I try from another account (regular member account ) it doesn't work.

After a small research, I understand it's caused by Autor's permission and no one except me will get a result and fox fix this issue I need to execute the query from the backend.

So this what I did : 
I wrote this code on the backend `data.jsw` file

```
export function gatMembersData(participate) {
            let options = {
  "suppressAuth": true,
  "suppressHooks": true
};  


return  wixData.query("Members/PrivateMembersData",options)
    .hasSome("_id",participate)
    .find()

    }
```

and get the query result on the frontend

```
import {gatMembersData} from 'backend/data.jsw';

gatMembersData(participate)
     .then((Qresults) => {ParticipantData1 = Qresults.items})
```

I thought it should solve the problem, the backend now executes the query so there is no difference if I run the code from my account or another member, but this code also working on my account but doesn't work on other members.
How to solve this issue ? how to get this query for any member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be like below

```
return wixData.query("Members/PrivateMembersData")
.hasSome("_id", participate)
.find(options)
.then( (res) => {
   return res;
});
```

Make sure that the variable "participate" is an array